# How to print type of `&dyn Error` in Rust

Tags: rust

I have the following function and want to include the "real" type behind `&dyn Error` in the error formatting string:

```rust
fn error_chain_fmt(
    e: &impl std::error::Error,
    f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>,
) -> std::fmt::Result {
    writeln!(f, "{}\n", e)?;
    let mut current = e.source();
    while let Some(cause) = current {
        writeln!(f, "Caused by: \n\t{}", cause)?;
        current = cause.source();
    }
    Ok(())
}

impl std::error::Error for MyError {
    fn source(&self) -> Option<&(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)> {
       ...
    }
}
```

to something like this:

```rust
fn error_chain_fmt(
    e: &impl std::error::Error,
    f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>,
) -> std::fmt::Result {
    writeln!(f, "{}\n", e)?;
    let mut current = e.source();
    while let Some(cause) = current {
        writeln!(f, "Caused by: ({}) \n\t{}", format_type_of(cause), cause)?;
        current = cause.source();
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn format_type_of<...>() -> String {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Relevant but only useful if you're making your own trait: [Get name of concrete type in trait](/q/74409479/2189130)

Comment: There is an experimental function, [`std::any::type_name_of_val`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/fn.type_name_of_val.html), but that says it *"does not resolve trait objects"*.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The `Error` trait does not expose that information and its not something inherent to dynamic trait objects.

Comment: `Error` does include `TypeId`, though, and there was work (currently not merged) to include the type name in `TypeId` (to avoid collisions), and there was some talk IIRC to also maybe expose it, so maybe somewhen (_far_) in the future we'll be able to do that :)